# Debug symbols of dll project

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have dll project in my Visual C++. I have compiled DLL debug version, copied to external program location and executed external program which is created in C#.

I would like to attach to running process and start debugging. I do Debug->Attach to process, select host client program and press attach.

But my breakpoints are not active an I see warning:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

Do I need somehow to load my dll debug symbols? Is Visual C++ is not able to load symbols from output directory itself?

Maybe I need C# host application debug symbols?

Comment: Put the `pdb` file into the same directory as the `dll` that is being loaded by the `C#` project.

Comment: @RichardCritten C# folder contains subfolder where dll is located. I placed pdb file in both locations - executable and dll , but this not helped.

Comment: Click the Select button in the Attach dialog and ensure both Native and Managed debuggers are selected.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General, untick the "Enable Just My Code" checkbox.  If that doesn't help then tell us what the Debug > Windows > Modules says about that DLL.

Comment: Make sure the .DLL and .PDB come from the same build. If these are not matched, the VS debugger will not load the .PDB. You can also use the "Debug | Windows | Modules " toolwindow, to explicitly load the .PDB by right clicking on the module, and selecting "Load Symbols". If the .PDB fails to load, it's most likely due to the .PDB file not matching the .DLL or .EXE being debugged.